# C++ JWT token expires immediately when linked with some other codes

Tags: c++, jwt, linker, c++-chrono

I'm using this JWT token [library](https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp). It worked just fine along with C++ Restbed library until I compile and link it with another C++ project. That other project is kind of confidential so I cannot show that code but when I compile it with my Restbed and JWT token implementation, JWT token immediately expire. Even if I don't call anything from that other project and simply linking its .cpp files with CMake's "add_executable()" function makes it happen.

The problem with JWT token is like that:

[image]

When I create the token, I sign it with `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` and set expiration at `std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds{50}`. When I `std::cout` these values, they give right values as above (start and end) but somehow JWT generate same token every time and even the first one expire immediately, also despite the values of start and end times different somehow verifier gets "iat" and "exp" claims as same.

That other project, uses `<time.h>` and `<sys/time.h>` some places and use these for some duration calculations, as far as I can see it doesn't change something with the system clock and it doesn't also use `<chrono>`. I cannot understand how does a code that wasn't even called interfere with JWT library. Also I've debugged where JWT creates token with GDB but it doesn't go to another function or anything beside from expected points. Does anyone have any idea what kind of problem I should be looking for in that other library or any strategy I can try.

Answer (score 0):

`iat` and `exp` in your example above are the same and point to GMT `Sat Feb 28 2015 08:46:36`. Are you assigning these values to the token claims in the right way? Maybe a problem with conversion of types?

Comment: I'm supplying these values as:                                                                                          `auto token = jwt::create()
    .set_issuer("auth0")
    .set_issued_at(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
    .set_expires_at(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds{3600})
    .sign(jwt::algorithm::hs256{"secret"});`                                                                       ( start = std::chrono::system_clock::now(), end =  std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds{3600} )